# problems generating ASDoc

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, asdoc

I am using [ASDocr](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/01/asdocr_simple_a.html), which is an Adobe AIR application GUI interface for the command-line Flex `asdoc` documentation generator. My class uses several external libraries and it is generating a 1046 error when creating the documentation:

```
/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/src/com/pingpongestudio/timeline/Timeline.as(1569): col: 39 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SWFAddressEvent.
private function handleSWFAddress(e:SWFAddressEvent):void {
                                    ^
```

As you can see I am using `SWFAddress` but only the `SWFAddressEvent` class throws an error. Lines 40 and 41 of that class (Timeline.as) are:

```
import com.asual.swfaddress.SWFAddress;
import com.asual.swfaddress.SWFAddressEvent;
```

This is the command-line instruction:

```
/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/bin/asdoc -source-path "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/src" -output "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/doc" -doc-sources "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/src" -lenient
```

My application works just fine. The compile errors show up only when generating the documentation. This application uses AS3 script files in combination with a FLA interface file.

---

EDIT

I added the external library paths just as they are in FDT to the compiler and now it throws this command-line instruction:

```
/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/bin/asdoc -source-path "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/src" -output "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/doc" -doc-sources "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/src" -library-path+="/Users/mga/Desktop/stuff/as3 classes/dashedline" -library-path+="/Users/mga/Desktop/stuff/as3 classes/webdevils" -library-path+="/Users/mga/Desktop/stuff/as3 classes/as3corelib-.92.1/src" -library-path+="/Users/mga/Desktop/stuff/as3 classes/swfaddress-2.4/dist/as/3" -library-path+="/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc" -library-path+="/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/frameworks/libs/flex.swc" -library-path+="/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/frameworks/libs/framework.swc" -library-path+="/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/frameworks/libs/rpc.swc" -library-path+="/Applications/Adobe Flex SDK 4/frameworks/libs/utilities.swc" -library-path+="/Users/mga/Desktop/stuff/as3 classes/greensock-tweening-platform-as3" -lenient
```

The error generated is the same.

If I try to exclude dependencies I get "Error: exclude-dependencies can not be used with doc-sources."

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `-library-path` parameter when you call the application, and include either "/Users/mga/Documents/FDT Workspace/vgline/libs" or the locations of each of the swc or swf files you're referencing.

You may also want to use the `-exclude-dependencies` flag to avoid generating documentation for third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks. If I select "exclude-dependencies" I get "Error: exclude-dependencies can not be used with doc-sources."